# creating a help command for my discord bot

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, command, bots

I am trying to create a help page that lists all the commands for my discord bot...

currently everything is coming through as Undefined within the discord and I am confused as to why.

Here is my help.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('help')
    .setDescription('Lists all available commands'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        let str = '';
        const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

        for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const command = require(`./${file}`);
        str += `Name: ${command.name}, Description: ${command.description} \n`;
        }

        return void interaction.reply({
        content: str,
        ephemeral: true,
        });
    },
};
```

I could try to do the v12 way, but I am trying to make a bot that is completely up to date with v13...

Comment: You can't just pretend that elements returned from `readdirSync` is first a string, then magically becomes an Object. I also don't know why in the world you would want to do `return void interaction.reply(...)`; why not just remove `return void`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all of your commands are structured like the code you presented, you were only missing a couple things. First was that the command name and description would be under `command.data` not just `command`. Also with `let` you can leave it empty (as I have) and fill it with anything.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('help')
    .setDescription('Lists all available commands'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        let str
        const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

        for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const command = require(`./${file}`);
        str += `Name: ${command.data.name}, Description: ${command.data.description} \n`;
        }

        return interaction.reply({
        content: str,
        ephemeral: true,
        });
    },
};
```

Comment: Awesome that worked. You will have to forgive me for the naive question as I am only a 2nd year CS student. But the way I have built the command file is similar to a node in the sense that I have to use .data to access the data within it (unless I used getters in setters) this is of course more of a Java way of handling data I believe?